# Godady Code First MIgration from ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-migrations

I have created a ASP.NET MVC5 project and I am hosting the website in Godaddy.
I am facing a problem when doing code first migration. When I add Enable-Migrations, Add-Migration Initial create and Update-Database from Nuget, Only ASP.Net Identity table and two database context table gets created in Godaddy Database and a new copy of all the table will be created in my local SQLEXPRESS server. 
I have tried to recreate  the migration Several times but changes.
Eg: I have database table A,B,C,D,E,F and ASP.NET Identity table 1,2,3,4.
In Godaddy after running Migration 1,2,3,4,E,F table get created and In local .SQLEXPRESS A,B,,C,D,E,F gets created. 
At present no matter how many times I delete the migration folder, drop both tables from Godaddy and Local SQLExpress server the result is the same.

When I run Enable-Migrations I get the Error

```
More than one context type was found in the assembly 'Hotel'.
To enable migrations for 'Hotel.Models.DatabaseContext', use Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName Hotel.Models.DatabaseContext.
To enable migrations for 'Hotel.Models.ApplicationDbContext', use Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName Hotel.Models.ApplicationDbContext.
```

So I select

```
Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName Hotel.Models.DatabaseContext
```

and tried with ApplicationdbContext, but will get an error when created the data for the table (A,B,C,D,E,F).

How can I move all my table to GoDaddy database.

Comment: Does the constructor of the context have a connection string that points to the desired database?

Comment: After updating the connection string and deleting the data base few times it started to work.